# node.js convert my express method to async/await

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

im having doubts to convert my express method to use async/await .

At this moment, my method looks like:

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
const body = req.body;

let hospital = new Hospital({
    name: body.name,
    user: req.user._id
});

hospital.save((err, hospitalCreated) => {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            ok: false,
            mensagem: "Error to create hospital",
            errors: err
        });
    }

    res.status(201).json({
        ok: true,
        hospital: hospitalCreated
    });
});
```

});

As im new with node, i try to put like this:

```
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
const body = req.body;

let hospital = new Hospital({
    name: body.name,
    user: req.user._id
});

await hospital.save((err, hospitalCreated) => {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            ok: false,
            mensagem: "Error to create hospital",
            errors: err
        });
    }

    res.status(201).json({
        ok: true,
        hospital: hospitalCreated
    });
});
```

This is the correct way to achieve this? Do i have to use try/catch? what is the best approach to this?

Thanks

Comment: Is the hospital.save() a method you could share? Or is it another library?

Comment: @MagdKudama I believed he use mongoose, but native mongo drive would also work.

Comment: Start reading docs about what async/await is and what it isn't. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: @MagdKudama im using mongoose. you can learn more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose

Comment: And I don't know what is the reason you want to use `async/await`. The benefit you can get is they will fall to the error handler if there is an error, and your code would look much cleaner. But you need to wrap your middleware by `.catch(next)`

Comment: For the beauty of async/await, one of the author of mongoose already wrote this, check it out: http://thecodebarbarian.com/80-20-guide-to-async-await-in-node.js.html

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the `async` and `await` generators is to avoid using callbacks. What you have done might work if the `save` method always returns a `Promise` and calls the callback, but this approach defeats the whole purpose of the generators. You should remove the callback and use `try` and `catch` instead.

```
try {
    await hospital.save();
    res.status(201).json({
        ok: true,
        hospital: hospital
    });
} catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({
        ok: false,
        mensagem: "Error to create hospital",
        errors: err
    });
}
```

Comment: Your answer will always catch by error, because there is no `hospitalCreated`. To avoid this, simply replace it by `hospital`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can move `hospital.save` to an async function with Promise resolve and then use await for getting the response and catch to get the error from the promise, like:

**UPDATE by using mongoose callback:**

```
function saveHospital(hospital) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            hospital.save((err, hospitalCreated) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(error);
                }

                resolve(hospitalCreated);
            });
        });
    }

    app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
        const body = req.body;

        let hospital = new Hospital({
            name: body.name,
            user: req.user._id
        });

        try {
            const hospitalCreated = await saveHospital(hospital)

            res.status(201).json({
                ok: true,
                hospital: hospitalCreated
            });
        } catch(error) {
            res.status(400).json({
                ok: false,
                mensagem: "Error to create hospital",
                errors: err
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a bad answer, (1) if you fail in creating a document, you will get error warming you can not send header twice. Your last `return` in `catch` chain is redundant; (2) Mongoose return a promise, you don't need the extra clothe of Promise.

Comment: For (1) that is why I add a `return` after `res.status(400).json({
          ok: false,
          mensagem: "Error to create hospital",
          errors: err
      })` and for (2), sure if you are using promises with mongoose and just change `await saveHospital(hospital)` for `await hospital.save()`, but if you are using mongoose with callbacks, could be an approach.

Comment: You still not get my point, your argument in catch is a function, which have it's own lexical scope.  What you are doing is you are telling the computer you finished your function execution in `catch`, and if you added `.then()`, that is the function will receive the return value, which is `undefined`.  The `return` you added is not stop the execution in its parent scope.

Comment: Also, I think your concept on `Promise` is a bit shaky.  For my second point, since mongoose will return a promise if there is no callback provided, you don't need to deal with callback.  If you get an error, you just handle it directly on the `catch` chain  That is why promise is beautiful.

Comment: @LeoLi Got it, was my error of understanding. But I have a doubt about mongoose, you said that if you do not provide a callback, mongoose will return a promise, this functionality is available on version >= 5?

Comment: Yes, but I remembered it was supported since Mongoose 4.x, so you don't need to promisfy the callback, it have been covered.  But be aware, there are some exceptions. You should visit their documentations.  (but IMO, their page is not user-friendly)

Comment: @LeoLi Cool! But if we suppose that we are using old Mongoose version < 4.x, creating and using `saveHospital` async function, will be an approach?

Comment: You may want to take a look on this [post](http://thecodebarbarian.com/80-20-guide-to-async-await-in-node.js.html) the author covered more than what I can explain in a comment.

Comment: You don't need the promise wrapper, and you have `async` without an `await`

Comment: @AluanHaddad You are right about having `async` without and `await`